# Which issue is the "reboot"/"new era" of Witchblade comics?

Tags: comics, top-cow-universe, witchblade

When looking at Comixology's [Witchblade page](http://www.comixology.com/Witchblade/comics-series/798), I noticed that the header announced:

> A **new era starts** in the Witchblade saga with the creative team of Ron Marz (The Darkness, Green Lantern) and rising artistic star Michael Choi! **This new-reader-friendly issue is a perfect introduction to Top Cow's flagship character.** Someone wants New York City Police detective Sara Pezzini dead, and not even the powerful supernatural artifact called the Witchblade will be enough to keep her from harm. **If you've never read Witchblade, this is the place to start!**

However, I failed to see which specific issue among the "Recent Additions" set on that page this description referred to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, upon some further digging, I have figured this out, so I'll answer myself in the best traditions of insanity :)

Since "Michael Choi" as an artist seemed to be the key to the new start, I searched comixology web site for "Michael Choi".

This brought up 2 hits in the series list ("Abattoir Vol. 1" and "Witchblade"), and 5 individual comics issues (Witchblade #80, #81, #85, #92, and "The Art of Witchblade").

Since the last one was clearly not a real comic issue, I looked at the earliest issue # ([**Witchblade #80**](http://www.comixology.com/Witchblade-80/digital-comic/AUG041619)).

Lo and behold, its description matches the description I quoted in the question 100%!

Answer (score 1):

The first issue of the reboot is Witchblade #151.